# How to use hikaricp in Java application

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, c3p0, hikaricp

Please could anyone guide me on how I can switch to HikariCP connection Pooling Framework in my Java/Servlet application? I am currently using c3p0 but I am having performance issues with it. I have seen a couple of examples as regards using HikariCP in a java application but they all seem to require a maven dependency (pom.xml) stuff which I am completely unfamiliar with as I never required that with c3p0 or my Netbeans project. I work with Netbeans IDE just so you know. Also, if this pom.xml is compulsory can it be uploaded into my application's WEBINF directory just like the web.xml? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

HikariCP is just a library like c3p0 is a library. Both can be added like maven dependencies if you use a Maven (or Gradle) project, or you can just download the library and attach it to your project yourself just like you did for c3p0.

This is the same for all Java libraries.

The [HikariCP project](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) relies on https://search.maven.org/ to link to downloads, but this has been broken recently by a redesign of search.maven.org. You can find the latest version on https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/jar

For the rest it is just a matter of checking the documentation.

Comment: The `rest` statement deserves +1